# Food Survey Application

Tags: vb.net

Okay so this code is a list of items in a combobox and you have to pick one item and then choose a radiobutton like or dislike and then hit vote.The results list box should total up all the votes every time you click like or dislike and hit vote. When I click like and press vote nothing shows up in the results box but when I hit dislike and press vote it shows up and the total is correct for the like I pressed and hit vote so it shows 1 for each. It stays that way the whole time while the program is running, so if I hit like 3 more times it won't update in list box until I hit dislike and press vote. How do I code to show up and update on both like and dislike votes?

Here is my code:

```
Public Class FoodSurveyForm

   Dim votes As Integer(,) = New Integer(0 To 3, 0 To 1) {}

   ' handles Food Survey Form's Load event
   Private Sub FoodSurveyForm_Load(sender As System.Object,
      e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

      foodsComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0 ' select first food in list
   End Sub ' FoodSurveyForm_Load

   Private Sub voteButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles voteButton.Click

      Dim index As Integer = foodsComboBox.SelectedIndex

      'if statement to add like and dislike votes
      If likeRadioButton.Checked Then
         votes(index, 0) += 1
      ElseIf dislikeRadioButton.Checked Then
         votes(index, 1) += 1
         DisplayVotes()
      End If
   End Sub

   Sub DisplayVotes() 'call DisplayVotes sub procedure

      resultsListBox.Items.Clear()

      'header for resultListBox
      resultsListBox.Items.Add("Menu Item" & ControlChars.Tab & "Like" _
       & ControlChars.Tab & "Dislike")

      For count As Integer = 0 To foodsComboBox.Items.Count - 1
         resultsListBox.Items.Add(foodsComboBox.Items(count).ToString & ControlChars.Tab & votes(count, 0) & _
              ControlChars.Tab & votes(count, 1))
      Next count

   End Sub ' Display Votes
End Class ' FoodSurveyForm
```

Comment: Nevermind! I got it!!

Answer (score 1):

DisplayVotes() must go outside of the if block:

```
    Private Sub voteButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles voteButton.Click

      Dim index As Integer = foodsComboBox.SelectedIndex

      'if statement to add like and dislike votes
      If likeRadioButton.Checked Then
         votes(index, 0) += 1
      ElseIf dislikeRadioButton.Checked Then
         votes(index, 1) += 1
      End If

      DisplayVotes()
   End Sub
```